# File difference in representation but not value

Tags: svn, webstorm, beyondcompare

BeyondCompare shows no difference between files (by value), but in WebStorm file is shown differently.

Can't find option to compare file properties history in BeyondCompare/Subversion.

What's the reason for this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to configure Beyond Compare to include Subversion properties in the mix, or asking us why the authors of the program have not implemented the feature? What's the screen-shot supposed to illustrate?

Comment: The right-hand side of your image appears to show the file with soft line wrapping (making the content fit without scrolling, without adding newline characters to it). This is usually a toggle option in your editor. Other than that, it's difficult to tell what you're actually trying to compare here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - i am asking how to configure BC to show difference in file properties - i think its the 1st thing u mentioned,

Comment: @alroc - i think you are right, thanks. The difference is stored in configuration in .idea folder, if i understand correctly?